# Can I just peek data of tcp socket buffer to check the data is what I want in linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I write a program to send 3 requests(lets say A, B, C) to the same server **through the same file descriptor** in linux, and then I use `recv` to wait for the msg(lets say A', B', C') back.

I receive msg back after server send msg back to me after 3 secs, and the server will send A', B', C' back to me not in order.

I expect **A got A'** and **B got B'**, but now A got B' because server send requests through the same file descriptor.

Can A keep waiting when A got B' and don't remove B' from socket buffre by `recv`?

Comment: Can you not just queue the out-of-order replies until the desired sequence is available?  I can't see how being able to 'peek' at the comms stack buffer would help any.  Just untangle the replies in user space.

Comment: Sounds like you want the API to do your work for you. You can't change the order that things are received. I'd advise you buffer data received and process it as required.

Comment: I would save the extra data in the application somewhere, rather than keep in the kernel's buffer. The socket buffer is limited... keeping the data unread might block the socket at some point.

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol. Either process the requests in-order, or if you want to multiplex them over TCP in an arbitrary order, use sequence numbers.

Comment: Or better still, if you really want parallel processing for the same client, which doesn't seem likely, use separate connections.

Comment: ^^^ that's what I'd do, (unless the server denies it).

Comment: If you could leave B' in the socket buffer then it wouldn't help you, because the first thing in the socket buffer would be B', so you'd never get around to reading A' out of the socket buffer because you'd have to read B' first.

Answer (score 1):

> I expect A got A' and B got B', but now A got B' because server send requests through the same file descriptor.

Not possible in TCP, unless the server is handling multiple requests on the same connection in separate threads, in which case the simple answer is: don't.

Comment: why impossible? In the situation like: client create 3 threads to send msg to server through the same file descriptor

Comment: It is impossible for TCP to deliver data out of order. The conditions I mentioned are exactly those in your comment. Is there something hard to understand about that?